# Cannot convert value of type error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dispatch-async, pedometer

I'm pretty new to Swift, so I'm following a tutorial on how to make a pedometer app from this page: http://shrikar.com/ios-swift-development-step-counter-app-using-pedometer-data/

However, that was from a while ago, so I've been working on updating it and not getting very far. I keep getting this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(CMPedometerData?, NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type 'CMPedometerHandler' (aka '(Optional<CMPedometerData>, Optional<Error>) -> ()')
```

Here's my code so far:

```
if(CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable()){
        let fromDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -86400 * 7)
        self.pedoMeter.queryPedometerDataFromDate(fromDate as Date, toDate: NSDate() as Date) { (data : CMPedometerData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(){
                if(error == nil){
                    self.steps.text = "\(data.numberOfSteps)"
                }
            }
        }

        self.pedoMeter.startPedometerUpdatesFromDate(newDay) { (data: CMPedometerData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(){
                if(error == nil){
                    self.steps.text = "\(data.numberOfSteps)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error occurs in the following line:

```
{ (data : CMPedometerData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(){
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The tutorial is old and you're probably using Swift 3 in your project.NSError has changed to be Error. You'll probably also run into other problems due to changes in Swift since the tutorial was published in addition to this.

Comment: Yep that's it, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It expects `Error?` whereas you have used `NSError?`. Try

```
(data : CMPedometerData?, error: Error?) -> Void
```

Comment: Wow, simple as that. Thank you so much.